# How to check if a variable is a certain type?

Tags: c#, .net

Yeah, sorry if my question wasn't asked right- im new, dont know all the rules. Thanks for correcting me, ill definitely keep these in mind for the future.

Basically, I'd like to know if there is a method in C# which checks a variable's type and returns a bool value.

Kinda like isinstance(variable, type) in Python.

Example for that:

```
x = "apple"
isinstance(x, str) -> returns true, because x is a string
isinstance(x, int) -> returns false, because x is not an int
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add a [mcve]? It's unclear what the type of the variable being "returned by the player" is

Comment: Please note that the tagging guidelines state that you shouldn't place tags in your question title unless they're organically part of the question (i.e. it can be read as part of a sentence). I've removed the "c#" tag from your question title for you.

Comment: Why you return `System.Object` and not `IEnumerable<Card>`(which could be a single or multiple)?

Comment: _"Is there a way to check if the PlayedCard variable returned by the player is a single card or an array?"_ - I'd expect that the returned value to be an array with 1 item or an array with several items. Returning a single card or an array of cards doesn't seem the right way to do this IMHO.

Comment: `if (playedCard is Card[] array) .. do something with array` But something seems wrong here - can you show us the code?

Answer (score 3):

> Each player object returns a PlayedCard variable. If the player puts down one card, the PlayedCard will be a single Card object, if the player puts down multiple cards, it will be an Array of Card objects.

Frankly, this is not a good idea.

On of the great strengths of C# is its strong type system. Once your program compiles, a lot of potential bugs are already gone.

I suggest the following alternatives (in order from simple to complex):

- Always return an array. If the player puts one card down, return a single-element array.
- Or wrap the array in a custom object with exactly the properties you need (`bool PlayedSingleCard => backingArray.Count == 1;`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You want the `is` operator

```
if (playedCard is Card card)
{
    //do single card stuff
}
else if (playedCard is Card[] cards)
{
    //do things with the array
}
```

You could also consider making the second check be on `IEnumerable<Card>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: This code begs for refactoring. Why `playedCard` can have different types?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because that's precisely what the OP asked for. It may be a bad idea, but that's still the question here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: if i search the title on SO i will certainly find a lot of duplicates. But we're here to help others to write better code not only to answer (wrong) questions.

Comment: One can do both. For instance, the other answer here gives a better approach, but fails to actually answer the question that was asked. Knowing how to check for a given type *is* useful, even though it may not really be the best solution here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes exactly, thats why i have commented

Comment: I was wondering if that is bad practice in general or just in this specific case.

For example I have a an abstract class that gets inherited by two further abstract classes which then result in real implementations.

These represent ability effects. Some objects I want to allow to use both abstract branches. Other classes are just supposed to use one of these.

For classes that can use both types i use their parent class for the field name and check whether they belong to one branch or another using "is" and then casting it to the specific branch.